# A chain homotopy that does not arise from a homotopy of spaces?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, homological-algebra

Algebraic topologists like to cook up algebraic invariants on topological spaces in order to answer questions, so they are often concerned with how strong those invariants are. Currently, I am concerned with just how much information is lost when moving from a space to `the' chain complex associated to that space.

Now, I should be a bit more specific here. There are many homology theories in which one takes a space, cooks up a chain complex, and takes its homology. I am mainly interested in just singular homology for this question, but if you can only think of an answer using sheaf cohomology or some other homology theory then that's alright. Now, the actual question is:

> Do there exist two spaces that have chain homotopic associated chain complexes, but are not, themselves, homotopic?

I imagine that, unless the answer to the question is "no," it would be a bit difficult to show that the two spaces are not homotopic, since we have taken away the tool we usually use to prove such facts. My first thought was that one might be able to cook up a counterexample by looking at two spaces whose compactifications give different homologies... but I wasn't able to come up with anything immediately. (Another method may be looking at homotopy groups... but they're so hard to compute, I didn't even try this approach). I probably didn't give this as much thought as I should have, so if the answer to this question is somewhat trivial, then go ahead and scold me and I'll go put some more effort into thinking about it.

Comment: Any chain complex is homotopy equivalent to its homology, so your question reduces to asking whether there are non-homotpic space with isomorphic homologies, and this is classical.

Comment: What does this mean? That a chain complex is chain homotopic to the homology groups regarded as a complex? Any complex that is not acyclic can't have that property.

Comment: You've heard of cup products? They reflect more structure in the singular chains than just that of a chain complex. The chain complex of a space does indeed forget a lot about the space, but if it is regarded as some sort of more refined algebraic object then it forgets less.

Comment: My previous comment was for Dylan. This one is for Josh. Think again. The homology of $H(C)$={the homology groups of $C$ regarded as a complex (with boundary maps all zero)} is isomorphic to the homology of $C$. And in fact if $C$ is a complex of free abelian groups then there is always a chain map $C\to H(C)$ inducing that isomorphism.

Comment: Note that this is a peculiarity of complexes over the integers. Looking for instance at the action of $\mathbb Z/n$ on $S^3$ giving rise to lens spaces, you get different complexes over the group ring of $\mathbb Z/n$ for different actions.

Comment: @Domenico: Is that really true in general? I can see that it would hold for split complexes (so it holds in this case), but complexes in general?

Comment: One has to be careful. Complexes are in general not homotopy equivalent to their homology complexes (if they are the homology would be a direct factor of the complex which is not true if the complex is free and the homology has torsion). I guess everyone was thinking of quasi-isomorphic.

Comment: @Torsten: I was talking about homotopy equivalence, but maybe what I was wrong regardless.

Comment: I assumed that Domenico was thinking of quasi-isomorphism, which is sometimes called weak equivalence. Any bounded below chain complex of R-modules admits a quasi-isomorphism from a chain complex of free R-modules, and any quasi-isomorphism between complexes of free modules is a chain homotopy equivalence, so that classifying chain complexes up to quasi-isomorphism is the same as classifying chain complexes of free modules up to chain homotopy equivalence. When the ring is $\mathbb Z$ then the complex is determined up to quasi-isomorphism by its homology. 

Comment: Josh: Of course the statement that a chain complex is chain homotopy equivalent to its homology does not place any restrictions on its homology, because whatever you want the homology to be you can choose the chains to be that. If you were only allowing complexes of free $\mathbb Z$-modules, then the only constraint is that the homology modules must be free.

Comment: Yes, I was thinkng of quasi-isomorphisms. Sorry for having called it homotopy equivalence: working too much with dglas one gets the awful habit of thinking of complexes of vector spaces rather than of arbitrary modules..  Thanks for having fixed that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A bounded below complex of free $R$-modules is acyclic if and only if it is contractible (in the sense that the identity map is chain homotopic to zero). Since the singular chain complex of a space is constructed out of free $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, any space with no homology would have to contract to a point, which is not the case (check out the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acyclic_space) for some examples/references).

Thus the chain homotopy exhibiting contractibility of the identity does not come from a topological homotopy.

Comment: And more generally, a complex is split exact if and only if the identity map is null-homotopic... I'm surprised I didn't think of this! Thanks for the answer!